# Regex pattern not working for input pattern match

Tags: javascript, regex, html

```
<input type="text" id="url" name="url"  pattern="/ ^(http:\/\/www\.|https:\/\/www\.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)(amazon)|(flipkart)+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$ /" required />
```

The displayed is my input. But I am unable to match any input. It should correctly match any website starting with http://flipkart.com or http://amazon.com. I checked on rubular. The expression is correct. Where am I wrong . please help . Thank you./

Comment: Remove delimiters `/` and carets `^` and `$`.

Comment: @Tushar Hey! I tried that. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Is that a space between `/` and `^` in your pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following, it worked for me

```
<input type="text" id="url" name="url"  pattern="(https:[/][/]|http:[/][/]|www.)[amazon|flipkart]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*$" required />
```

Comment: I have verified in w3 http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_pattern and it was working fine for the user requirement

Comment: I have tried toto's that worked. Will try this too. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Thanks for correction @WiktorStribiżew corrected my answer

Comment: This `[(flipkart|amazon)]+` will match `))))))))))))))))))`

Comment: Thank a lot  @WiktorStribiżew , corrected my answer and  correcting my myself :)

Comment: Still, you have not read about [**character classes**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): *With a "character class", also called "character set", you can tell the regex engine to match only one out of several characters. Simply place the characters you want to match between square brackets. If you want to match an `a` or an `e`, use `[ae]`.* Your `[amazon|flipkart]+` will match `||||||` or `aaaaaaaa`, or `fsfkrrrrt`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from: `(amazon)|(flipkart)+`, you need to group these two strings and remove the superfluous `+`.

```
(amazon|flipkart)
```

You couls also reduce the regex to:

```
(https?://(?:www\.)?)(amazon|flipkart)([-.][a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(/.*)?
```